# MS Access - Grouped query based on MAX field

Tags: vba, database, microsoft-access, sql

I am trying to build a SQL Query that takes the following data:

```
+-------------+--------+---------+---------+--------+
| Primary Key |   ID   | Version |  Class  | Fruit? |
+-------------+--------+---------+---------+--------+
|           1 | Banana |       1 | NORTH   | Yes    |
|           2 | Onion  |       1 | WEST    | No     |
|           3 | Orange |       1 | NA      | Yes    |
|           4 | Orange |       2 | PACIFIC | Yes    |
|           5 | Banana |       2 | EUR     | Yes    |
|           6 | Celery |       1 | EUR     | No     |
|           7 | Celery |       3 | SOUTH   | No     |
|           8 | Celery |       4 | SOUTH   | No     |
|           9 | Pepper |       1 | N-PAC   | No     |
|          10 | Pepper |       2 | N-PAX   | No     |
+-------------+--------+---------+---------+--------+
```

And returns ID of latest version and its corresponding data, where the criteria of `Fruit` is examined.

An SQL string would be needed to return ID with class for Max version where `Fruit = No`

**Results:**

```
+--------+-------+
|   ID   | Class |
+--------+-------+
| Onion  | NORTH |
| Celery | SOUTH |
| Pepper | N-PAX |
+--------+-------+
```

I only need to return the ID and it's class to store in an MS Access listbox.

I managed to build a Group By / Max query in the editor and was only able to get IDs to return grouped, but the corresponding data was not associated with the maximum version.

Thanks for your help and expertise.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways that you can achieve this.

The following examples all assume that your table is named `table1` and that your fields are `id`, `class`, `version` and `fruit` (not `fruit?`) - change these as appropriate to suit your data.

**Note:** the following examples assume that your `fruit` field is a **text** field. If your `fruit` field is actually a **boolean (yes/no)** field, then remove the single quotes around `'No'` in the following examples.

---

#### Using a joined subquery:

```sql
select u.id, u.class
from table1 u inner join
(
    select t.id, max(t.version) as mv
    from table1 t
    where t.fruit = 'No'
    group by t.id
) v on u.id = v.id and u.version = v.mv
```

Here, the subquery selects the greatest `version` for each `id` for records where `fruit = 'No'` and this is then joined to the complete dataset to return the required fields for each `id` and `version`.

---

#### Using a correlated subquery:

```sql
select t.id, t.class
from table1 t
where t.fruit = 'No' and not exists
(select 1 from table1 u where u.id = t.id and u.fruit = 'No' and u.version > t.version)
```

Here, the selection is performed entirely within the `WHERE` clause, which, for every record, tests whether there exists another record in the set with the same `id` and a greater `version`, and if so, the record is not returned.

---

#### Using a `LEFT JOIN` with unequal join criteria:

```sql
select t.id, t.class
from table1 t left join table1 u on t.id = u.id and t.version < u.version
where t.fruit = 'No' and u.id is null
```

This example can only be represented in MS Access in the SQL view, as the MS Access Query Designer cannot display joins which have equal join criteria (i.e. where one field equals another).

This example is similar in operation to the correlated subquery, but the selection is performed by the join, rather than within the `WHERE` clause.

---

Finally, note that your given example result is incorrect: the `class` for the maximum `version` for `id = 'Onion'` should be `WEST`, not `NORTH`.